# The grammar method for a special kind of ing verbs

Tags: grammar

I have recently encountered the following **I had saved more of the money I made working at the restaurant** and my question is which grammar method is used for the word **working** here ?

Comment: [A **participle phrase** is an adjective phrase that starts with a participle](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/participle_phrases.htm) (***working***, in the case of your example).

Comment: @FumbleFingers The non-finite verb clause *“working at the restaurant“* is acting **adverbially *not* adjectivally** because it modifies either the entire clause *“money (that) I made”* — or if you prefer just the verb *made* — and describes “how” the action was done.  It is fully equivalent to the adverbial prepositional phrase ***“by** working at the restaurant“* in this regard. One can often omit the preposition from adverbial phrases like this one, leaving behind only the bare verb clause with that constituent’s functional relationship to the rest of the sentence wholly unchanged.

Comment: @tchrist Actually, I didn't understand your last sentence. My question is when can we omit the preposition in a prepositional clause ?

Comment: @EKH I don't think that tchrist is saying that prepositions can systematically be omitted from preposition phrases, but rather that if the prep "by" is dropped from the PP _by working at the restaurant_, its complement (the non-finite clause _working at the restaurant_), would still  be an adjunct (adverbial), though it would probably be an adjunct of place rather than a manner adjunct like the PP.